# How to type `control + [` on a German iPad Smart Keyboard

Tags: ios, ipad, smart-keyboard

How do you type `control + [` on the German Smart Keyboard for iPad.

I am missing the "Esc" on the iPad keyboard a lot in order to discard text fields. I read that `control + [` might work as a replacement.

How do you type this on a German keyboard layout with `[` not being a dedicated key.

Answer (score 2):

I had an issue where I couldn't get a question mark to appear using the Apple iPad Smart Keyboard with the German as the language, I would switch back to English for punctuation. I just found that you can have the language set as German but then change the keyboard hardware settings to English and now my question mark button give me a question mark. Yay! 
So it may work for your situation too. On your iPad go to Setting > General > Keyboard > Keyboard hardware.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use command with period: `⌘` + `.`

Tested with German, Swiss German and English in Safari.